# Extracting text before and after the splitting point including the splitting character in R

Tags: r, regex, string

I have an expression in the following format

```
(<decimal_no><space><operator><space><decimal_no>)<space><operator><space><decimal_no>
```

I'm trying to split an expression (5.0 - 50.0) - 15.0 into two parts (5.0 - 50.0) and the rest of the string " - 15.0" into a list. With the following R code I'm able to split it into two parts successfully.

```
expr = "(5.0 - 50.0) - 15.0"
unlist(strsplit(expr, "(?<=\\))", perl = T))

#output 
"(5.0 - 50.0)" " - 15.0"
```

However when the string pattern is changed "15.0 - (5.0 - 50.0)" I want to separate the string into two elements "15.0 - " and "(5.0 - 50.0)". I can do a workaround but I want to know can this be done with a regex similar to the previous method (?<=\)) ?

```
expr2 = "15.0 - (5.0 - 50.0)"
unlist(strsplit(expr2, "(\\()", perl = T))

#output
"15.0 - "     "5.0 - 50.0)" #extracts the strings but the splitting character is missing
```

I think the regex (?<=\)) means get all the characters before ")" including the ")". I tried using few variations (?>=\(), (\(>=?), (\(<=?), (\(?\)) but nothing worked.

Edit: Sample strings

```
"(5.0 - 50.0) - 15.0" -> "(5.0 - 50.0)"," - 15.0" 
"15.0 - (5.0 - 50.0)" -> " - 15.0", "(5.0 - 50.0)"
"(43.0 - 85.0) + (18.0 + 84.0)" -> "(43.0 - 85.0)", " + ", "(18.0 + 84.0)"
"((12.0 + 89.0) - 73.0) - (58.0 - 90.0)" -> "(12.0 + 89.0) - 73.0) - " , "(58.0 - 90.0)"
```

Comment: Well `(?<=\))` does not mean what you say you think it means. It's a positive lookbehind ensuring what precedes is a literal right parenthesis `)`.

Comment: Can you post multiple samples of strings you expect and what their expected outcomes should be?

Comment: @ctwheels Thank you for the reply. I updated the question with sample expressions I'm working with.

Comment: [`(?(DEFINE)
  (?<a>\h*[+-]\h*)
  (?<n>\d+(?:\.\d+)?)
  (?<g>\((?:(?&n)|(?&v))(?&a)(?:(?&n)|(?&v))\))
  (?<v>(?&g)|(?&n))
)
((?&v))(?:((?&a))((?&v)))*`](https://regex101.com/r/jopf02/1)? You'll have to remove spaces and pass the parameter of `perl=TRUE` for it to work in R

Comment: Most of your examples are achievable, except the last one. Regex is a more-or-less context-free language (talkin' [regex engines, not formal Regular Expression theory](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-vs-regular-expression.html)), so very, very few regex engines support nested expressions. .NET is the only one that comes to mind, though I believe there may be a couple others.

Comment: @ctwheels thank you for your comment. Your regex worked. Also I found out how to do the lookahead https://regex101.com/r/8ikYV4/2